# Number of roles and emojis. Discord.js

Tags: typescript, bots, discord.js

I want to make a serverinfo command for my discord bot, and I want to make a field that displays the number of the roles and another for the emojis.
Can someone tell me how to do it?

This is my code:

```
async runCommand(args: string[], msgObject: Discord.Message, client: Discord.Client): Promise<void> {

        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("Server Info")
            .setImage(msgObject.guild.iconURL)
            .setDescription(`${msgObject.guild}'s information`)
            .addField("Owner", `The owner of this server is ${msgObject.guild.owner}`)
            .addField("Member Count", `This server has ${msgObject.guild.memberCount} members`)
            .addField("Emoji Count", `This server has ${msgObject.guild.emojis} emojis`)
            .addField("Roles Count", `This server has ${msgObject.guild.roles} roles`)

        msgObject.channel.send(embed)
            .catch(console.error);
}
```

The code gives me this:

Server Info

Test Server's information

Owner

The owner of this server is @ItamarD

Member Count
This server has 3 members

Emoji Count

This server has [object Map] emojis

Roles Count

This server has [object Map] roles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the Discord.js API documentation for [Guild objects](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=emojis) you will notice that Guild.emojis and Guild.roles returns a Collection.

The [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) is an extension of [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which has a convenient size property you can use.

The resulting 2 lines code would be:

```
.addField("Emoji Count", `This server has ${msgObject.guild.emojis.size} emojis`)
.addField("Roles Count", `This server has ${msgObject.guild.roles.size} roles`)
```

Answer (score 0):

that my code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(":serveurinfo")) {
        let si = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("Server Info")
        .setDescription(`${message.guild.name}'s information`)
        .addField("Owner", `The owner of this server is ${message.guild.owner}`)
        .addField("Member Count", `This server has ${message.guild.memberCount} members`)
        .addField("Emoji Count", `This server has ${message.guild.emojis.size} emojis`)
        .addField("Roles Count", `This server has ${message.guild.roles.size} roles`)

    message.channel.send(si);

    }
```

And for emoji and roles, the answer is: This server has undefined emojis and This server has undefined roles

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
if(message.content.startsWith(":serveurinfo")) {
        let si = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("Server Info")
        .setDescription(`${message.guild.name}'s information`)
        .addField("Owner", `The owner of this server is ${message.guild.owner}`)
        .addField("Member Count", `This server has ${message.guild.memberCount} members`)
        .addField("Emoji Count", `This server has ${message.guild.emojis.cache.size} emojis`)
        .addField("Roles Count", `This server has ${message.guild.roles.cache.size} roles`)

    message.channel.send(si);

    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.